# How can i tell which executor an ignite compute job is going to run for

Tags: ignite

I want to be able to manage the number of jobs that are active per executor - I had planned on implementing the CollisionSPI for this, when a new job arrives that is waiting on an executor which is "full," the new job could be rejected. But I don't see any way to determine the executor name in the ComputeJobContext or ComputeTaskSession. Is this supported or would I have to embed this as an attribute into the session itself?

Comment: Isn't it always `"pub"`?

Comment: No you can do `IgniteCompute.withExecutor(name)` to use a custom executor with the given name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `ComputeTaskSession` to internal `GridTaskSessionImpl` and calling `executorName()` from there. If it helps, please file a [ticket against Apache Ignite JIRA](https://Issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE), to add this method to interface.